# MongoDB Vs Cassandra Vs PostgreSQL Vs MySQL

Tags: mysql, mongodb, cassandra, database-performance

### General

I have to store everyday 100 millions of records composed in this way:
`id name time`. The unique key is `id`, but I have to do the searching on `name` and `time`.

I have to chose a database like MongoDb or Cassandra or others but I don't know their performance in order to write this logs in the database and retrive them.

My necessity is that the writing operation is very very fast also more than the reading/searching. I wish to use the indexes in order to be faster for the search and I can use some cluster in order to split the data like the shard in mongoDB.

My hardware is not so performance, I'm using Docker and for each container I can have max 8 GByte of ram and 500GByte of hard disk in SSD technology. The operation system is Ubuntu. The container could not stay on the same machine and they comunicate with a LAN.

I wish to know which database is the fastest in order to write my logs.

### The schema of the database

The database is composed by two tables:

- The main table (named table A) is formed:

  - `id` is a string of max 30 chars and it is the primary key
  - `name` is a string of max 60 chars (from 30 to 60 chars) and it has an index in order to perform the search and it is unique key.
  - `time` is a string of max 60 chars (from 30 to 60 chars) it has an index in order to perform the search and it is unique key.

The input are the files very very long (10 millions of records) and this input files are given every day.

After one year this table will be 365 x 100^6 tuples and in two years
will be 2 x 365 x 100^6 and so far.

- The second table (named table B) is formed:

  - `field` is a string of max 60 chars (from 30 to 60 chars)

This table is updated (add or remove tuples) every two or more hours.

### Query

The main request is:

```
select *
from A, B
where field = time OR field = name
```

and this request is done every time that the table B is updated or if it is not possible every day. But the duration of the search cannot be more than 1 hour.

For me the most important item is that the database is very very fast when it has to import the files on table A. I can accept also to stop the insertion for the table A and the update for table B when the search runs. But I cannot be slow when I put the new records on the table A from the files. I must be the most faster possible when I insert the new records (or import the files).

### Others information

- I wish one day also to insert the replication data like the RAID 1 in order to be sure don't lose any data.
- On SSD there is the journalism in order to avoid any data loss.
- The number of records of rows inserted per second must be as fast as possible. This is the most important critical issue of my problem.

> 120 rows INSERTed per second. Do they arrive one row at a time? Or a whole day's worth at a time? Or something else?

The records arrive from some files, each file has a lot of records. The number of records can be 1 until inf. The files arrive sometimes, there is not a specific time slot. But I have the possibility to wait some hours before to insert a new files in order to process it (maybe to change the format from CSV to JSON or doing some checks about the format) or if the db is importing a previous file.

> Is it a "log" file? Or CSV? Or something else? Please provide a sample.

The input file can be a CSV, JSON file or others. I have the possibility to modify this before the import. An example of file can be:

```
id,              name,               time
9999999999999   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA     18Agust201819h90m90s
1233423434333   zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz    Monday18Agust201819h90m91s
000244200002    BAJDHFURI8DNCJUED    sds3444324sssdds34343ddff
0000000000003   ZXEWSFFSJFajf8392    Monday18Agust201819h90m94s
1123884000334   1AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA    Monday18Agust101819h90m95s
3334442000005   1zz2zz244z34sASd3    fff3320000001010101011111s
```

- The dimension of the file can be 10Gbyte or more or less, there is not a specific rules. But I have the possibility to wait some hours in order to merge some files and to import one big files.
- `id` is own id
- `name` is a special "hash" of the log that the department/app/user has given to the database.

> What kind of "time" is provided as a 36-60 character string? Please provide a sample.

The `time` in reality is a general string because each applications/department/offices has own format. But also in this case could be considered like a special "hash".

> 10M rows per day --> 500GB per year. So the disk will fill up in one year? What part needs to change to handle the data you expect to receive?

All these logs cannot be pruned. This database is a data lake of the enterprise in order to collect all the logs.

> Will you be purging data after, say, 90 days? (This will solve my previous point, but needs a special schema for efficiency.)

All these rows cannot be pruned.

> `where field = time OR field = name` is not practical. Please describe in words what the intent is. We will need to express the query some other way.

Sometimes we receives a file to search in the `TABLE A` but we cannot know if the string is linked to field `NAME` or `TIME`. Because this file is created by a very very old application.

> `100^6 = 100*100*100*100*100*100` = 1 trillion. I don't think you meant that.

Yes, I think it and it is an optimistic number :( Nowadays my office collects 5Gbyte of logs in several format (JSON, CSV, etc...) every hour. We are in developing phases. The final scenario is that the all the logs are stored in this database. I image that the max pick could be also 50Gbyte every hour.

In the past all the logs are collected in normal hard disk. In 10 years my department has collected about 100TByte of data but only for old departments and offices. Now there are new departments so I suppose that we will have more logs than previously.

The goal of the project is to collect in one database all the logs of the society, for instance when the user Alpha has opened a computer, or the user has done a login for checking the e.mail and more others. Or also if the user wishes to create a special logs in order to have a proof. But it is only an example of application of this database. Other is that the db is the share db from others db.

For example: the user Bravo has sent an e.mail to Tango. Tango claims that Bravo has not done it. Bravo can retrieve the log using his  department log database. Now Bravo asks us if we have a specific tuple, if the tuple exists on own database Bravo has a proof that has sent the mails.

Comment: Please provide the schema and main SQL queries.  With those, we can better understand your app and judge the efficiency of various solutions.  More important than number of records is the number of rows inserted _per second_ and whether they must be inserted individually versus can be batched in some way.

Comment: If the input is log files, how much lag are we allowed between the item being logged and when it needs to be found in a search.  A lot more performance and scaling can be achieved if that time constraint is, say, one hour, not one second.

Comment: I have added the information @RickJames I hope that I have added all the information that you have asked me. I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Since community has closed this question, @RickJames please give a look to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68787113/best-database-engine-for-very-large-data-ingestion

Answer (score 2):

(Not yet an Answer, but too long for a Comment.)

- 120 rows INSERTed per second.  Do they arrive one row at a time?  Or a whole day's worth at a time?  Or something else?
- Is it a "log" file?  Or CSV?  Or something else?  Please provide a sample.
- What kind of "time" is provided as a 36-60 character string?  Please provide a sample.
- 10M rows per day --> 500GB per year.  So the disk will fill up in one year?  What part needs to change to handle the data you expect to receive?
- Will you be purging data after, say, 90 days?  (This will solve my previous point, but needs a special schema for efficiency.)
- `where field = time OR field = name` is not practical.  Please describe in words what the intent is.  We will need to express the query some other way.
- `100^6` = `100*100*100*100*100*100` = 1 trillion.  I don't think you meant that.

(Addressing most issues...)

- RAID, drive "journaling", etc, are partial solutions to the risk of data loss.  They are handled at a lower level; nothing in SQL or MySQL configuration is involved with such.
- Each CSV file (of 1 to INF number of rows) is best loaded via `LOAD DATA`.  It *may* be better to load it directly into the main table, or it *may* be better to load it into a temp table, massage the data, then copy it into the main table.  (I don't have enough details to predict which is better.)
- A huge CSV file loaded directly into the main table will *probably* block some operations.  In this case, it may be important to go through a temp table.  Then, the rows could be copied into the main table in chunks, thereby minimizing impact.  More on chunking: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks  (That talks about `DELETE`, but can easily be adapted to the `SELECT` needed in your application.)
- You say that `time`, by itself, is Unique?  Not two events can happen in the same second?
- `name` and `time` are unique?  There are pros and cons about picking between `INDEX` and `UNIQUE`.  `UNIQUE` will slow down `INSERT` because of the need to check for uniqueness before finishing the Insert.  I don't (yet) see any benefit for `UNIQUE` over `INDEX` _for your application.
- Abnormal "time" format -- Don't plan on doing ranges or comparisons other than `=`.  As you say, think of it as a 'hash'.
- No pruning?  The data lives in this table for years?  Well, what will you do about disk space if there is a 500GB/year growth rate?
- You will have

  ```
    INDEX(name),   -- (or UNIQUE(name))
    INDEX(time)    -- (or UNIQUE(time))
  ```
- The query you propose should be changed to this for performance.  (`?` will become the same quoted 'hash'.)

  ```
    SELECT * FROM A  WHERE name = ?
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM A  WHERE `time` = ?
  ```
- `A` may need some kind of timestamp based on the log file that it came from.  I would expect some queries to get thousands of results, and the user might want only "recent" results.  [OK, that conflicts your statement that `name` and `time` are unique, in which case the above Select can return only 1 or 2 rows.]
- Even if `A` becomes multi-terabytes, the above Select (with the above indexes) will always run in milliseconds (assuming at most 2 result rows).  RAM size has essentially no impact on the speed.  The disk must be big enough to hold the entire table.  Furthermore, since HDD is still cheaper than SSD, it may be worth using HDD for the huge table.  (The query will probably still take less than 1.0 second, regardless of configuration.)
- If you expect the table to be bigger than 32TB, we need to do something extra.  That is a hard limit, but there are ways to get around it.  If this will be a problem, start a new Question that focuses only on the table size (plus table schema and main Selects).  The number of rows won't hit a limit, just the byte size.
- Since a new "log" arrives hourly (or whenever), the table in inherently not "up to date".  That is, a Select won't find records that happened in the last hour or so.  Hence, I don't worry about whether the loading of the CSV takes up to, say, an hour to run.  The "chunking" I mentioned above add a little time, while avoiding blockage.  So, I strongly think that the chunking is the "right" way to go based on the dataflow and other requirements.
- When is `id` generated?  Is it ever "used"?  Does include the name of the log from which it came?  I am asking because: it takes space, it may be slowing things down, don't you need a "log id", maybe it could be tossed, there are better things than varchar(60) to have as the PK, etc.

Comment: I have replied all your questions :)